# iterating with regex over a text

Tags: python, regex

i have the following raw text:

```
acl number 3049 name SCAN-49-OUT
 description Scanner VLAN 49 ACL Outbound
 hardware-count enable
 step 10
 rule 0 permit ip destination 192.168.49.21 0
 rule 65530 permit ip destination 224.0.0.18 0
 rule 65534 deny ip
acl number 3050 name condur-out
 step 10
 rule 0 permit tcp source 28.1.122.12 0 destination 28.1.114.12 0 destination-port eq 9001
 rule 10 permit tcp established destination 28.1.114.12 0
 rule 30 permit tcp established destination 28.1.115.128 0
 rule 40 permit tcp source 28.1.119.128 0 destination 28.1.114.12 0 destination-port eq 9000
 rule 60 permit tcp source 192.85.168.22 0 destination 28.1.114.12 0 destination-port eq 22
 rule 80 permit tcp source 192.85.168.22 0 destination 28.1.114.12 0 destination-port eq 9443
 rule 90 permit tcp source 28.1.115.128 0 destination 28.1.114.12 0 destination-port eq 9000
 rule 100 permit tcp source 192.85.168.22 0 destination 28.1.115.128 0 destination-port eq 443
 rule 65534 deny ip
acl number 3051 name tom-out
 step 10
 rule 50 permit tcp source 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination 28.1.113.0 0.0.0.127 destination-port eq 1556
 rule 60 permit tcp source 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination 28.1.113.0 0.0.0.127 destination-port eq 13724
 rule 70 permit tcp source 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination 28.1.113.0 0.0.0.127 destination-port eq 13782
 rule 80 permit tcp source 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination 28.1.113.0 0.0.0.127 destination-port eq 10082
 rule 90 permit tcp source 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination 28.1.113.0 0.0.0.127 destination-port eq 10102
 rule 160 permit ip source 192.85.168.0 0.0.0.255 destination 28.1.113.0 0.0.0.127
 rule 5100 permit icmp icmp-type echo
 rule 5110 permit icmp icmp-type echo-reply
 rule 65500 permit tcp established destination 28.1.113.0 0.0.0.127
 rule 65534 deny ip
acl number 3052 name jerry-out
 step 10
 rule 50 permit tcp source 28.1.113.0 0.0.0.127 destination 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination-port eq 1556
 rule 60 permit tcp source 28.1.113.0 0.0.0.127 destination 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination-port eq 13724
 rule 70 permit tcp source 28.1.113.0 0.0.0.127 destination 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination-port eq 13782
 rule 80 permit tcp source 28.1.113.0 0.0.0.127 destination 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination-port eq 10082
 rule 90 permit tcp source 28.1.113.0 0.0.0.127 destination 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination-port eq 10102
 rule 110 permit ip source 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255
 rule 120 permit tcp source 192.85.168.22 0 destination 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination-port eq 3389
 rule 130 permit udp source 192.85.168.22 0 destination 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255 destination-port eq 3389
 rule 5100 permit icmp icmp-type echo
 rule 5110 permit icmp icmp-type echo-reply
 rule 10210 permit ip source 155.61.32.0 0.0.3.255 destination 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255
 rule 10220 permit ip source 192.85.168.0 0.0.0.255 destination 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255
 rule 65500 permit tcp established destination 28.1.112.0 0.0.0.255
 rule 65534 deny ip
```

i'm trying to iterate over the text above with the following regex pattern:

```
acl\snumber\s\d+\sname\s([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+)((\s\s)(description)?\s?(\s[a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+)\s\d+\s([a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+))?(\s\shardware-count\senable)?(\s\sstep\s\d+)?\s\srule\s\d+\s(permit|deny)\s[a-zAZ]+(\s(established))?(\ssource\s\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\s\d+)?(\sdestination\s\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\s\d+)?(\sdestination-port\seq\s\d+)?
```

but it only works for a few first lines
and i would like to find a way to start from `acl number` till `rule 65534 deny ip`

i have tried a few lookahead and lookbehind but no luck....

does anyone have any idea how could i make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked much better for me

```
re.finditer(r'(\snumber)\s(\d+)(?s)(.*?)(\nacl|\s#)', config, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.findall` in dot all mode:

```
inp = "acl number 3049 name SCAN-49-OUT ..."
matches = re.findall(r'acl number \d+.*?rule \d+ deny ip', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

Comment: maybe i have expressed the desired output wrong
```
inp = "acl number 3049 name SCAN-49-OUT ..."
matches = re.findall(r'acl number \d+.*?rule \d+ deny ip', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

it works but it doesn't break into multiple groups

eg i want permit to be a group, rule source to be a group and the IPs to be a group too.

Comment: What output do you want to see if not all content in between the two marker lines?

Comment: if i would see something like 
output1
```
acl number 3049 name SCAN-49-OUT
 description Scanner VLAN 49 ACL Outbound
 hardware-count enable
 step 10
 rule 0 permit ip destination 192.168.49.21 0
 rule 65530 permit ip destination 224.0.0.18 0
 rule 65534 deny ip
```

and so on, it's also good